# Bash for loop with function

Tags: bash, curl

How to make the command inside this for loop execute?

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {8..12}
do
    printf "curl \"http://myurl?hour=20140131%02s\" -o file%02s.txt\n" "$i" "$i"
done
```

the current version of my script prints out the following lines:

```
curl "http://myurl?hour=2014013108" -o file08.txt
curl "http://myurl?hour=2014013109" -o file09.txt
curl "http://myurl?hour=2014013110" -o file10.txt
curl "http://myurl?hour=2014013111" -o file11.txt
curl "http://myurl?hour=2014013112" -o file12.txt
```

I'd like to change the script so that each line is executed and a file is saved at each curl request.

Comment: Just remove `printf` and the double-quotes.

Comment: Not sure I understand, which double quotes? all of them? If I remove all but the escaped ones it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use eval, you can make it simple:

```
for i in {8..12}; do
    printf -v n %02d $i
    curl -s "http://myurl/?hour=20140131${n}" -o "file${n}.txt"
done
```

Comment: The builtin printf allows you to: `printf -v n %02d $i`. That's faster since it does not have to spawn a subshell, but suffers in readability.

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman: I often forget that `-v var` option in `printf`

Comment: @chepnerL That worked for me on `GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release`

Comment: There I go again, forgetting which version of `bash` adds various non-POSIX extensions :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to evaluate the generated command:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {8..12}
do
    eval curl $(printf "'http://myurl?hour=20140131%.2i' -o file%.2i.txt" "$i" "$i")
done
```

Also you can use the simplified code:

```
for i in $(seq -f "%02g" 08 12)
do
    curl "http://myurl?hour=20140131${i}" -o file${i}.txt
done
```

Comment: I strongly recommend against this. While it would work, there are safer alternatives that don't involve `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `bash` 4, there's no need for `printf`:

```
for i in {08..12}
do
    curl "http://myurl?hour=20140131$i" -o "file$i.txt"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

just add another line without printf

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {8..12}
do
   printf "curl \"http://myurl?hour=20140131%02s\" -o file%02s.txt\n" 
   x=$(printf "%02d" "$i")
   curl "http://myurl?hour=20140131$x" -o file$x.txt 
done
```

Comment: The point of the `printf` is to force a leading zero for single digit values of `i`.

Comment: @chepner  ok, i made the changes , %02d adds zero and not "%02s"